# postgresql regex extracting names based on multiple delimeters

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql, split

## Problem Description:

I'm getting really hung up on trying to reformat the name field within the following table. Observations within the name field are non-atomic, and I am just trying to return a single name instead of the names/old ids within parenthesis, or secondary/tertiary that names delimited by comma, semicolons, or 'OR'. I am very new to sql and any regex insight would be greatly appreciated!

## Reproducible example:

```
create table myTable(
    id varchar(255),
    name varchar(255)
);

insert into mytable(
    id,
    name)
    values(
        'N6BMTW-D',
        'NOUGAT (WAS X25TW)');

insert into mytable(
    id,
    name)
    values(
        'N2BHXS',
        'JESTER (WAS X13SX)');


insert into mytable(
    id,
    name)
    values(
        'N2BHS-C',
        'APRIL STAR (WAS X13S-C)');

insert into mytable(
    id,
    name)
    values(
        'N2BHS-AG',
        'JOY (LITTLE SPECKLES)');

insert into mytable(
    id,
    name)
    values(
        'M1',
        'M; Real M; Mort');


insert into mytable(
    id,
    name)
    values(
        'M7D',
        'OS, SEBASTIAN');


insert into mytable(
    id,
    name)
    values(
        'M9',
        'K OR BOBBIE');
```

## Actual output:

```
select * from mytable;

    id    |          name           
----------+-------------------------
 N6BMTW-D | NOUGAT (WAS X25TW)
 N2BHXS   | JESTER (WAS X13SX)
 N2BHS-C  | APRIL STAR (WAS X13S-C)
 N2BHS-AG | JOY (LITTLE SPECKLES)
 M1       | M; Real M; Mort
 M7D      | OS, SEBASTIAN
 M9       | K OR BOBBIE
(7 rows)
```

## Desired output:

```
select * from mytable;

    id    |          name           
----------+-------------------------
 N6BMTW-D | NOUGAT
 N2BHXS   | JESTER
 N2BHS-C  | APRIL STAR
 N2BHS-AG | JOY
 M1       | MORT
 M7D      | SEBASTIAN
 M9       | BOBBIE
(7 rows)
```

Comment: I have no idea what the rules are for the last three.  They seem totally arbitrary.

Comment: Any help addressing even one of these cases would be appreciated. Worst case scenario, I'll have to manually update some of the arbitrary observations by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace everything after (and including) the " (".  This handles the first three:

```
select regexp_replace(name, ' [(].*', '')
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely gets the majority of the job done!